# Nested foreach in javascript in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, foreach, nested

I am creating an ASP.NET MVC application where I display a google map with coordinates from a database. I am a rookie at this and I have got stuck on an issue with nested foreach loops...
On the C# Razor page I have a JavaScript function "Initialize" in which I loop through an array of objects containing the coordinates and create a polyline based on them and then add it to the map. This works fine and the code looks like this:

```
var latLongCoordinates =
[
    @foreach(var itemFlightState in Model.QARFlights[0].FlightStates)
    {
        <text> new google.maps.LatLng(@itemFlightState.PresentPosLatDec.ToString().Replace(",", "."), 
               @itemFlightState.PresentPosLongDec.ToString().Replace(",", ".")),</text>
    }
];

var flightPath = new google.maps.Polyline({
    path: latLongCoordinates,
    geodesic: true,
    strokeColor: '#FF0000',
    strokeOpacity: 1.0,
    strokeWeight: 2
});

flightPath.setMap(map);
```

However, I need to display several different polylines  (one for each flight) and therefore need to use a nested foreach loop to achieve this but it doesn't work. I would like to surround the example above with another foreach loop to plot all flights and not just the one with index 0 as in the example above. The following is what I would like to do:

```
@foreach (var itemQARFlight in Model.QARFlights) {
    var latLongCoordinates =
    [
        @foreach(var itemFlightState in itemQARFlight.FlightStates)
        {
            <text> new google.maps.LatLng(@itemFlightState.PresentPosLatDec.ToString().Replace(",", "."), 
                   @itemFlightState.PresentPosLongDec.ToString().Replace(",", ".")),</text>
        }
    ];

    var flightPath = new google.maps.Polyline({
        path: latLongCoordinates,
        geodesic: true,
        strokeColor: '#FF0000',
        strokeOpacity: 1.0,
        strokeWeight: 2
    });

    flightPath.setMap(map);
}
```

When adding the surrounding @foreach everything below turns red and it seems the parser does not understand what I mean at all any more.

Sorry if this is a trivial question but I really cannot manage to get around it. Any help would be greatly appreciated!
Best regards
Ulrika

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that `@foreach` brings you back to C#, so you need to wrap your JavaScript again in `<text>`.

```
@foreach (var itemQARFlight in Model.QARFlights) {
    <text>
        var latLongCoordinates =
        ...
        flightPath.setMap(map);
    </text>
}
```